# Prevent from single words in line in centered text

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, wordpress

I am building a website with WooCommerce, WordPress and Elementor. I am trying to prevent that only one word is in a line. I tried with hyphens, word-break, line-break… nothing worked out. Does someone have an idea for that. Here is a screenshot of what I mean:

https://ibb.co/16QHRxC

This is the link:
https://world-taste.de/produkt/marokkanische-kalbstajine-mit-pflaumen-cousous/

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre], and then edit your question accordingly. Why just posting a link to your site is not enough, is explained under https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: Given the font size there's no way to avoid the orphan word, unless you want to make the view scroll horizontally, but that would be a terrible solution. Simple fix: make the font smaller.

Comment: You can look into preventing widows: https://www.binarymoon.co.uk/2017/04/fixing-typographic-widows-wordpress/ bur actually, there is no reason for the and to be on it's own - looks like a markup issue, ie, the way you have copied and pasted text into that field.

Answer (score 0):

Add non breaking space to the small words if you could edit the html, for example
`Die Pflaumen (enthalten Kerne) sind sauer und werden durch Hinzugabe` becomes

```
Die Pflaumen (enthalten Kerne)&nbsp;sind sauer&nbsp;und&nbsp;werden durch Hinzugabe
```

There isn't a one stop solution to this. The above one works on the idea that you append very small words with non breaking space on both sides, so that when it overflows, it drags along with it the accompanying words to the next line.

If you know some css, another basic idea would be to add

```
/* line-name class is assigned to a span inside 
the long text which you don't want to break at all */
.line-name {
white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Reference [Here](https://alligator.io/css/prevent-line-break/)